# Like to reveal the content help?

Tags: php, facebook, iframe

I am trying to make a webpage so that content will only be visible after user likes the pop-uped iframe like button of facebook.

Can someone provide me any idea? I am new to programming in such things. But i want to do this experiment.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at the source code for something like this - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/like-gate/ - not the best solution out there but will give you an idea of what to do

Comment: Though trying to refrain from judging what other people do my first reaction was "oh no, not another buy-a-pig-in-a-poke-/experts-exchange³ page". Please elaborate...

Comment: @VolkerK: I am unable to understand what you want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Facebook's FB.Event.subscribe. More details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Instead of alert in the example, you check the response and on success, make an ajax request to fetch the content and display it.

Comment: I want like a ColorBox should appear and all content remains in dark, and only the Like button is visible in an iframe. After liking the page, the colorbox gets closed.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, do you any idea about how colorbox should be combined with the like event?

Comment: Use $.colorbox.close() to close the color box when you get the response from Facebook's subscribe event.